# Why does my delete not work for related tables using golang gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to issue a delete command to my postgresdb using GORM that will also delete the related records from another table.

When I use the code below it removes the main record but does not delete the records from the related table. What am I doing wrong?

```
type Record struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  RelatedRecords []RelatedRecord
}

type Relatedrecord struct {
  gorm.Model
  Col1 string
  Col2 string
  RecordID uint
}

func DeleteRecord(record_name string) {
    db = database.GetDB()
    var delrec Record
  

    if err := db.Unscoped().Select("RelatedRecords").Where("name = ? ", record).Delete(&delrec).Error; err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(recordname + " " + "deleted")
}
```

Comment: Are you using ["assotiations"](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Association-Mode)?

Comment: How are you checking for whether it was deleted or not? I'm asking because I see you are using `gorm.Model` which adds a soft-delete functionality, meaning it marks it as deleted rather than performing a `DELETE` SQL statement.

Comment: I am looking in the DB, and by using the db.Unscoped function it is supposed to delete the records without the soft delete option.

Comment: It deletes the primary record properly but not the related records.

Comment: You probably have to set up the on cascade options, https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html, at the foreign key section

Comment: Which gorm version you are using ?

Comment: I am using v1 https://v1.gorm.io/

Comment: Maybe this feature is not available in `v1`(as missing in doc), in `v2` it is [available](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select)

Comment: I will take a look